# jest unit test how to call a method in a method: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled() Expected number of calls: >= 1 Received number of calls: 0

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking

I find it very hard to write unit tests. My problem is how to check if child method was called, when parent method was called. What I'm doing wrong?
First I call service method, and expect that it would call mocked method?

DefaultDatabaseService.ts file method:

```
async deleteDatabase(): Promise<string> {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev') {
      try {
        await this.deleteParkingReservation();
        await this.deleteRoomReservation();
        await this.deleteParkingSpace();
        await this.deleteRoomSpace();
        await this.deleteUser();
        return `All database was deleted.`;
      } catch (error) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Could not delete database!', error);
      }
    }
    return 'You must use DEV environment for that!';
  }
```

my spec.ts file for unit test:

````
const modelStub: any = {
  exec: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  deleteDatabase: jest.fn(),
  deleteMany: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  deleteParkingReservation: jest.fn(),
  deleteRoomReservation: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  deleteParkingSpace: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  deleteRoomSpace: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  deleteUser: jest.fn().mockReturnThis()
};

describe('DefaultDatabaseService', () => {
  let service: DefaultDatabaseService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        DefaultDatabaseService,
        { provide: getModelToken('RoomReservationSpace'), useValue: modelStub },
        { provide: getModelToken('ParkingReservationSpace'), useValue: modelStub },
        { provide: getModelToken('RoomReservation'), useValue: modelStub },
        { provide: getModelToken('ParkingReservation'), useValue: modelStub },
        { provide: getModelToken('User'), useValue: modelStub }
      ]
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<DefaultDatabaseService>(DefaultDatabaseService);
  });

  it('should call deleteDatabase method', async () => {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'dev';
    await service.deleteDatabase();
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev') {
      await expect(modelStub.deleteParkingReservation).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }
  }); ```

and my output after calling this test:
````

DefaultDatabaseService › should call deleteDatabase method

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0

  39 |     if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev') {
  40 |       console.log('esam cia');
> 41 |       await expect(modelStub.deleteParkingReservation).toHaveBeenCalled();
     |                                                        ^
  42 |     }
  43 |     //   expect(modelStub.deleteRoomReservation).toHaveBeenCalled();
  44 |     //   expect(modelStub.deleteParkingSpace).toHaveBeenCalled();
```